# Is there an analog to the five factor model for emotion?

Tags: emotion, statistics, big-five

To the best of my understanding, the five factor model of personality comes from a factor analysis on a large list of adjectives that can be used to describe an individual's personality. It is validated, in some sense, by its usefulness in predicting behavior and life outcomes in a wide range of contexts.

It seems like something very similar could be done for emotion. I.e. list words describing a persons present state (angry, remorseful, sad, bitter, frustrated, etcetera) and do a factor analysis on those. Then, see if the resulting model (assuming that the analysis yields something useful) is predictive of shorter term / state dependent behavior.

Has any work like this been done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the most comprehensive system of describing human emotions or states of mind?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/8510/what-is-the-most-comprehensive-system-of-describing-human-emotions-or-states-of)

Comment: @BryanKrause That's very helpful, but I don't think it fully answers the question. The use of factor analysis gives the big 5 a nice statistical foundation where you can say such and such roughly orthogonal factors explain a certain amount of variance. I was hoping for something similar here. But maybe there isn't a strong analog to the big 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recently published [Atlas of personality, emotion and behaviour](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0227877) is possibly what you are looking for(Mobbs, 2020).  Over 3,000 emotions are included in the analysis, a summary of which is below.  The article has a more [comprehensive version](https://ndownloader.figstatic.com/files/21216930).  The five factor model was derived through factorisation whereas the atlas was developed using a lexical/network approach.

[image]

**References**

Mobbs AED (2020) An atlas of personality, emotion and behaviour. PLOS ONE 15(1): e0227877. https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0227877

**Declared Interest**

I am the author of the atlas paper.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It does appear to meet several of the criteria.